# web.config not app.config being published to xxx.dll.config in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, nunit

I have an ASP.NET project that outputs a class library as a dll which is then deployed to IIS. Per standard builds a config file is also output along with the dll as xxx.dll.config and it contains many useful environment variables such as connection strings (i.e. it conforms to the application settings architecture requirements).

In VS 2012 the contents of xxx.dll.config file were sourced from app.config in the project root directory.

In VS 2015 it appears xxx.dll.config's contents are instead sourced from web.config in the project root directory.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a ASP.NET application with VS2015.
2. Add a app.config file in this application.
3. Build this application.
4. Open the bin folder and find the application.dll.config file and open it. The content is the same with Web.config.
5. Do the same operations from Step 1 to Step 4 in Visual Studio 2012, the content is the same with App.config.

This is causing me a bit of a headache as I was relying on app.config to hold variables (connection strings,  auth providers) for my functional tests while web.config held variables for deployed code.

Most of the reading I've done on AppDomains and their configuration variables seems to indicate that web.config shouldn't factor into the build output unless explicitly instructed and even then it isn't exactly easy to transform a web.config file, nevermind have it end up as the xxx.dll.config file.

I could rework my test fixtures to set the environment variables directly from the tests but for things like ASP.Identity that requires writing quite a few new classes to load a RoleManager and associated providers which I'd like to avoid.

If anyone could suggest how to engineer the VS build to output a config file that is easily used by the assembly AND the nunit tests when run via the nunit runner or Resharper that would be awesome.

Comment: instead, you can add in your source control a new file *.dll.config  and copy the entries you want in that file.  That should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To restore the original behaviour of Visual Studio 2015 back to what I was accustomed to in Visual Studio 2012 I added a post build event:

1. Go to Project-> Properties
2. Select Build Events
3. Add the following to the "Post-build event command line" :

   copy /Y "$(ProjectDir)\App.config" "$(TargetDir)\$(TargetName).dll.config"

The .dll.config is now once again the App.config instead of Web.config